# Defining a formal Primitive Recursion

Tags: functional-style, recursion

I'm searching for a way to define the function [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function#Definition) call **Primitive Recursion**. It should have two functions as argument and it should return a function. I need this as helping in studying mathematical recursion theory. I need another help with a similar problem; this time i want a "primitive minimization", that is a function called primMin a try i made inspired by @Rojo is.

```
primMin[f_] := Module[{h},
    h[x___Integer] := Module[{}, For[i = 0, f[x, i] != 0, i++,]; i];
    h]
```

this take f a two argument function and return a one argument function that given x as an argument and search for the first second argument so that f[x,#] == 0. this code work but i couldn't find a way to substitute the For with a Map or something similar. I need that given x there is no y so that f[x,y] == 0 then program will crash or continue to run forever. 
thank

Comment: Hello! What have you tried, where are you getting stuck, and etc etc? (Typical questions so we feel enablers of your MMA learning and not unpaid employees )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a sketch of a solution that only required on the fly translation from the article, done by someone who has no idea what he is doing. See if it helps (and if it works)

```
primRec[f_, g_] := Module[{h},
  h[0, x___Integer] := f[x];
  h[ym1_Integer, x___Integer] := With[{y = ym1 - 1},
    g[y, h[y, x], x ]
    ];
  h
  ]
```

I think this would be a pure function version.

```
prRec[f_, g_] :=If[#1 === 0, f[##2], g[#1 - 1, #0[#1 - 1, ##2], ##2]] &
```

Comment: This is exatcly what i needed my problem were i hadn't familiarity with function like With or Module, I will be testing this and eventually report any misbehavior if any